# Develop Windows Phone on Visual Studio 2013 On Windows 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, visual-studio-2013

I own a Windows 7 (Home Premium) and Visual Studio 2013.

As a part of a project for Uni, we are required to write an application for Windows Phone, basically - they require for Windows Phone 8, but I even think that Windows Phone 7 will do.

My question is this: 
Other than installing Visual Studio 2012 + WindowsPhone7 SDK or Installing Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2013, or using a VM with one of these - 
Is there a way to develop for Windows Phone 7 or 8, under Windows 7???

I don't currently have a physical windows phone and will have to use an emulator for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows phone 8/windows store apps under windows 7 OS is not possible, you need a windows 8 OS

You can develop for windows phone 8/windows phone 7 (7.1) with windows 8 OS

Windows 7 OS obviously supports windows phone 7 development

[See this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uk_faculty_connection/archive/2012/11/02/windows-phone-8-sdk-requirements.aspx)

there are other hardware requirements such as Hyper V for windows phone 8 emulator support in windows 8 OS

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

You can keep both versions of VisualStudio on the same machine, but keep in mind that if you want to develop applications for Windows8 or WindowsPhone8 on Windows7 operating systems this is not possible because you miss the new framework WindowsRuntime, so I advise you to keep windows 8 as operating system, VisualStudio 21012 + sdk for WindowsPhone7 and VisualStudio 2013 SDK for windowsphone 8 and developments already built for Windows Phone8.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot develop a WP8 app on Windows 7. You can develop a WP7 app on Windows 7 using VS 2010 plus the WP7 SDKs - WP 7.1 SDK, WP7.1.1 SDK, WP7.8 SDK - http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/01/22/now-available-windows-phone-sdk-update-for-7-8.aspx.